# Why is it that I can't reference a global variable directly in PHP?

Tags: php

**I'm curious to know why the following code behaves differently?**

*The following does not work:*

```
$_variable &= global $_global;
echo $_variable;
```

*The following works:*

```
global $global;
$_variable &= $_global;
echo $_variable;
```

?

Comment: @Pekka: Nice answer, but why do we have to use `global` anyway? I know a lot of languages where you don't need to specify within a function that a (global) variable from outside that function is needed.

Comment: @Marcel Since PHP is dynamically typed, with the variables created on the fly, there's no specific declaration. Strongly-typed languages (or even ones that make you declare the variable) have you declare the variable in one instance, in one scope, and that one is used as long as it is in scope, and has not been overridden with a newer version of the same name.  Since there is no formal declaration, PHP assumes that you're always declaring it local scope, allowing you to re-use variable names.

Comment: I know that as a general rule one is discouraged from using global variables, but sometimes one is forced to (I'm programming Drupal and it's impossible to do anything interesting without calling a global variable here and there -- like the global $user for instance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the `global` keyword more like a verb than an adjective. Your first example says "reference assign the global known as $_global to $_variable". But `global` is not an adjective. The second example, which is correct, says to php, "Treat $_global as a global", or "global-ify $_global", and then make the assignment.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`global` is a special language construct, it can't be used in operations as you do in example 1.

Answer (score 2):

The `global` keyword is used to say, "Use the global variable by this name, rather than a local one."  The most common use is like this:

```
$name = 'Slokun';

printName();
function printName() {
    global $name; // Use the global, rather than function-local, version
    echo $name;
}
```

which would print

```
Slokun
```

Compare to:

```
$name = 'Slokun';
printName();

function printName() {
    echo $name;
}
```

which wouldn't print anything

Comment: This is not exactly the answer to what's asked (well, according to the (wrong) title, it is): it is clear the OP already knows about the `global` keyword, his question is rather: why can't I use the `global` keyword within operations, like I do in my first example?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be wrong. Passing a value by reference should be:

1.)

```
$_variable =& $_global;
```

2.)

```
$_variable = & $_global;
```

3.)

```
$_variable = &$_global;
```

1~3 are the same thing.